# How to write to the next line in a text box in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, visual-studio, textbox

My code writes to a text box and displays different lines of text using the SetTimeout function. But everytime it writes, it replaces the original text with the new text. What I would really like is for it to continue writing on a new line. I am very new to javascript so I need a little help with this. Here is my code so far:

```
putftp.onclick = function () {
    var Text = document.getElementById("TextBox");

    function firsttext() {
        Text.innerHTML = "This is the first test.";
        setTimeout(secondtest, 3000);
    }
    function secondtest() {
        Text.innerHTML = "This is the second test.";
        setTimeout(thirdtest, 5000);
```

I would like the output to be

*This is the first test.*

*This is the second test.*

instead of

*This is the second test.*

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to concatenate the contents of innerHTML together. Currently you're simply changing its value:

```
Text.innerHTML += "<br />This is the second test.";
```

Comment: the += does continue the code and thanks alot for that. But for some reason it fires an error with the "<br /> part. Any idea why?

Comment: Could perhaps be a character escaping issue. What browser is generating an error message and what is the error? Are you seeing the error here: http://jsfiddle.net/mXrGG/

Comment: No I am not. Which confuses me even more! lol. My error is occuring here Text.innerHTML += "<br />This is the second test."; 
it is saying it is a runtime error of some kind. I honestly have no idea now because your code is correct. Its interesting because when I take away the <br /> it works just fine.

Comment: ok new result. IE fires the runtime. Firefox doesnt add a new line and also writes the <br />, but I need it to run in IE. I will try and troubleshoot it.

Answer (score 1):

You are replacing the text, not adding to what it had. If you want to add lines, concatenate the current html with the new one you want to add:

```
putftp.onclick = function () {
var Text = document.getElementById("TextBox");

function firsttext() {
    Text.innerHTML =Text.innerHTML+ "This is the first test.";
    setTimeout(secondtest, 3000);
}
function secondtest() {
    Text.innerHTML = Text.innerHTML+"This is the second test.";
    setTimeout(thirdtest, 5000);
```